# Need help identifying adult tricycle

Tags: identify-this-bike, tricycle

I picked up an old adult tricycle to restore at a yard sale. It needs plenty of work and needs a bunch of new parts (spokes, fenders ect.), however I do not know anything about the tricycle except for the serial number that was found on the headtube. The numbers being HC0755083, I have seen no other identifiable markings, leaving me to wonder if it is perhaps a custom made tricycle. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Please upload photos. Without a photo or two we really can't help you. The serial number would possibly help the manufacturer identify the exact trike, but that doesn't help us.

Comment: Your new bike will use standard bike parts for almost everything.    Spokes will be normal, the front fender/mudguard will be normal.   The parts that could be odd will be the transmission from the chain out to the drive flanges on the two back wheels.  I'd recommend adding a front brake too.

Answer (score 3):

HC start to the serial number is for   Huffy Corp. . The front sprocket styling is common Huffy style . Likely mid/late 60's or early 70's production . Are the tires 24 x 1 3/8 ? these should be available at bike shops .  If your rear wheels have 28 spokes this is a lighter duty unit and replacement rims could be hard to find . Commonly equipped with a Shimano 3 speed coaster brake mid-hub and a Peerless differential (used on lawn equipment and go-karts ) yes 2 wheel drive . 
Good luck and happy hunting for restoration parts , patience too .

Comment: Yeah, the front fork is a classic Huffy design from 1970 or so.

Answer (score 2):

Most bike shops have access to parts for adult trikes, no matter who the manufacture was, taking the trike in is always a plus (I know it's a hassle) but call first to make sure your working with a shop willing to help you before you haul it in.
I've sent a message with the serial # to one of my vendors to see if it's one of their models (I'll respond later with an answer), no matter; adult trikes used pretty standard bike parts.
please upload Pics I'd like to see it.
later,

Sun trikes informed me that it's not one of theirs, and by seeing the pics 
it's probably not a (professional) custom built.
you should be able to find parts for it, just make sure the frame isn't compromised or it's just not worth fixing, you can buy a new one for 300-500 US.
I hope this helps & if you do decide to get rid of it gift it to a local bicycle collective they maybe able use parts off it.

Answer (score 1):

That is a Huffy 3 speed trike.

Comment: Welcome to the site - Yes, that is already in Hamish's answer from 2016.   Consider upvoting that answer instead of duplicating.  You can also take a moment to read the [tour] and learn how SE's Q&A format works.

Answer (score 1):

I have one of these and it's a Free Spirit Ted Williams Jr. Edition Tricycle. Shimano 3 speed hub. Sold by Sears and Roebuck. I Just started the restoration of mine.